# How do I colour every other category with gt()?

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

data <- 1:150 %>% sample(10) %>% iris[.,]

data
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica
26           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     setosa
142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica
91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
data %>% arrange(Species) %>% gt() %>% 
tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = '#F0FDEC'),
    locations = cells_body(
        rows = Species == 'setosa')) %>% 
tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = '#F0FDEC'),
    locations = cells_body(
        rows = Species == 'virginica'))
```

[image]

I don't want to manually specify which Species should be colourd so that the code can scale.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert to `numeric` (and `factor` before if it's not already the case) and set `TRUE` for every uneven group ids:

```
data %>% 
  arrange(Species) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
    tab_style(
      style = cell_fill(color = '#F0FDEC'),
      locations = cells_body(
      rows = as.numeric(Species) %% 2 == 1))
```

[image]

Comment: That's really clever. Thank you so much! The missing link for me was converting to factor and then to numeric.